# What should i return on null document?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Sometimes the variables doc or type are null.
So I tried to add first `if (type == null){....} else {....}`

But if it's null what should I return back ? 
Now I tried to use try and catch but since it's null then I get null exception in another class where im using this class.

```
public static HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument getHtmlDocumentWebClient(string url, bool useProxy, string proxyIp, int proxyPort, string usename, string password)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = null;
    using (MyClient clients = new MyClient())
    {
        clients.HeadOnly = true;
        byte[] body = clients.DownloadData(url);
        // note should be 0-length
        string type = clients.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
        clients.HeadOnly = false;
        // check 'tis not binary... we'll use text/, but could
        // check for text/html
        try
        {
            if (type.StartsWith(@"text/html"))
            {
                string text = clients.DownloadString(url);
                doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                //client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
                if (useProxy)
                {
                    //Proxy                
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyIp))
                    {
                        WebProxy p = new WebProxy(proxyIp, proxyPort);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usename))
                        {
                            if (password == null)
                                password = string.Empty;
                            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(usename, password);
                            p.Credentials = nc;
                        }
                    }
                }
                doc.Load(client.OpenRead(url));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    if (doc == null)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Doc is null   " + doc + " The link that did it was    " + url);
    }
    return doc;
}
```

The function get url's each time and on some specific url the variable type is null. The reason that the site need password or something.

How should I handle the null ?

Answer (score 2):

If `type` is `null`, apparently there is no `Content-Type` header in the response.

```
string type = clients.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
```

Then `doc` will also be `null` since the line `type.StartsWith` will throw a `NullReferenceException` that is swallowed by your general catch-clause (a very Bad Thing™).

If `type` is not `null` but `doc` is `null`, apparently the content-type doesn't start with `text/html`:

```
 if (type.StartsWith(@"text/html"))
     doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

Since your function is named `getHtmlDocumentWebClient`, I assume it is used to get a HTML document. When there is no such document (because you couldn't determine the content type, or the content-type was something other than `text/html`), then **yes**, your method should return `null` (*or* throw an exception). You only throw an exception when it is unexpected, but with web development it is not really unexpected when you get something other than a HTML document.

Then you handle the possibility of getting a `null` value whenever `getHtmlDocumentWebClient` is called. It depends on your situation what you do when there is no HTML document.

Note that the `Content-Type`, if present, may lie. For example, it may return `application/octet-stream` for almost anything.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  1) "content-type" may be omitted - or might be misleading.  2) If "content-type" happens to be missing ... then variable "type" (a *very* poor name for a variable, BTW...) will be null ... and "type.StartsWith()" will throw an exception ... *BEFORE* "doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()" gets executed.  Hence the "doc" null.

Comment: Could you show me please a complete solution for that how the class should look like how to handle the null ? The problem is that im calling this function from another class from inside a recrusive function so I need to handle the null maybe in the other places too. Or to return something else then null .

Comment: @user2065612 You should think of `null` as meaning _not present/unknown_. Whenever you encounter something that may possibly be `null` you'd have to ask yourself: is it unexpected and possibly a bug if this were `null`? Then throw an exception. Otherwise, propagate the `null` by letting your method return `null` (HTML document is _not present/unknown_) as well. Since your method may return `null`, you have to ask yourself the same question again. Rinse and repeat. I can't give you a complete code solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the result is null then your caller should handle it. If you could reasonably expect a null return argument then it's up to the caller to do a null test or you might consider throwing an exception if a null result is an error condition. In any case the caller should catch any potential exception and handle gracefully.